# How to pass multiple values to my SSRS Report from MDX

Tags: reporting-services, mdx

I need to pass multiple values to my parameter in ssrs report from MDX.
My Dimention :
`[Dimenction].[Heirarchey].[Month].&[09]&[2012]` this is internal parameter.

I need to pass multiple month names and single year to my parameter and then my parameter is going to populate the data from my dataset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible link:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-NZ/sqlreportingservices/thread/7f9cc219-1a57-4ddb-8bd5-5135e0aacbe6